prefer (don't force) https but allow http on Linux (html, or wordpress)
So I have 2 websites with https/ssl working fine, but on some browsers typing a url without a protocol defaults to using http, despite them supporting https. I want clients to be redirected to https only if their browsers support it (so the usual .htaccess 301 redirect won't work, nor will forcing https via wordpress plug-ins).
What I want is for all requests to be auto redirected to https UNLESS the browser doesn't support it - so no forcing https when it's not supported. (Adding https -> http where https not supported would be ideal but not essential eg for people linking in via search engines - I'm mostly interested in people on old browsers typing in the address or having bookmarked it)
All code I have seen so far is for forcing https (and disallowing http) eg via .htaccess.
Some very old answers I have seen mentioned preloading but I'm not clear on how, and not clear on why some browsers that do support https default to http. (Https has been available for 1-2 years at least).
Any solutions to prefer https but also allow http when no https is possible?
Platform is Linux shared hosting. One website is wordpress, one is html that may migrate to WP next year I wondered if there was a HSTS/headers or preloading solution? No subdomains in use.
[While I do understand 0.1% to 0.01% of traffic is generally coming from browsers, this is for a decades old website with many people loyally using it since the days of dial-up modems and phone cables.]
see also q13376219

"redirected to https only if their browsers support it" - I don't think there is an actual browser which does not support https, since it would not be able to use the majority of today's web.

As an aside and walk down memory lane, we had HTTPS in the days of dialup (I was running an ISP then and needed to make allowances for it when configuring ISP level caching!).   The versions we had won't work anymore, but per https://timelines.issarice.com/wiki/Timeline_of_HTTPS_adoption Netscape Navigator supported it in 1995.  Broadband only became a thing in the early 2000's

@SteffenUllrich, a number of browsers have optional SSL support.  Lynx, for example, can be built as an HTTP-only browser.

@SteffenUllrich This is actually a real issue, especially with older OSes (and indeed, it makes using many modern websites hard). While older browsers/OSes do support HTTPS, they likely don't support the most recent version of TLS. Since enabling old SSL/TLS versions on a server exposes everyone including modern clients to downgrade attacks, it's paradoxically more secure to offer unencrypted HTTP instead of TLS 1.0 for people stuck on an aging Android version, for example (because modern clients won't silently downgrade to HTTP).

I thought for a moment that this was a very, very, very old question which suddenly resurfaced, but apparently not. "Https has been available for 1-2 years at least)", you means 30 years? Do you actually know of any users of those sites with browsers which would not support https? Unless you are actually talking about something completely different, you can forget about that. Redirect all traffic to https and don't even think about it.

Note that if you allow using plain HTTP in any way, HTTPS-capable clients become vulnerable to protocol downgrade attacks, affording them the same security as plain-HTTP clients (i.e. none).

@mark we are over the mark where you could simply not to support https. Anyone compiling lynx without https support must assume it won't work on most websites [that matter]. In fact, it's already really hard to browse many websites without javascript support.

I'm not usually the one to advocate for designing a site with quirks for specific browsers, but in this niche case I think it might be helpful to figure out which specific browsers these stragglers are using, then target them by user agent.
The oldest browser I have experience with is Lynx (launched in 1992), and it's still actively developed in 2024 with full HTTPS support, so it leaves me to wonder: Are these people loading your pages using Telnet onto a dot matrix printer? Are they dialing in? Which historic browsers are they actually using?
Once you determine the (likely three or four) browsers these users are using, then you can add this to your HTTPS redirect to only target browsers that are not the extremely old ones:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(extremelyOldBrowser|extremelyOldBrowser2) [NC]


I agree with @MaximillianLaumeister answer - this answer just fleshes out some nuances and expands on his answer.
From the traffic I see, stuff talking on port 80 on my server is bot traffic - presumably something trying to save itself overhead of https.  (I'd love to block traffic based on this behaviour it but thanks to stupid AV scanners I can't).    very often the user agents are fake
I don't believe there can be a trivial way to implement what you ask, and I would not bother to implement this because HTTPS has been built into backend core libraries for a very long time, and any client that does not support HTTPS should not be speaking HTTP on the Internet.  (I've worded this sentence carefully - there are some IOT servers which don't handle HTTPS due to lack of resources so the reverse is not true - IOT clients should be able to revert back to http sometimes)
I posit you could create a solution where someone goes to the HTTP version of the site, which then attempts to download a resource over https (maybe an image, maybe javascript) and depending on whether that is successful redirect to https content or display the site in http.   I'm not a Javascript expert but if you are OK with browsers that can't handle Javascript going to HTTP then I posit this could work without to much coding.
Having this work in Wordpress might be extra tricky as Wordpress has a canonical URL - so you may need to hack that functionality or maintain 2 versions of the website.
HSTS headers are not the solution - they force browsers to remember to go to HTTPS in future to prevent downgrade attacks to HTTP.  I don't see how preloading can help either.
Of-course it may be possible to simply take a "Don't care" approach and ensure "http:" or "https:" is not sent with any server responses - in which case clients requesting HTTP will get HTTP and clients requesting HTTPS will get HTTPS - however this is not "preferring https" its welcoming all-comers equally.
The stack overflow post you link to is not going to be helpful in finding an answer as its tackling a much simpler and very common use case of redirecting HTTP to HTTPS.  Your case is very niche and can't be attacked using similar strategies because it requires knowledge of the browser which - other then by trusting the agent string the browser provides - is not something that can be done at the server level.

Our company actually does have an alternate case; the product installer detects missing dependencies (usually .NET 4.8) and downloads them. However due to the fact the dependency checker (by necessity) runs extremely early in install it doesn't have a guaranteed way to use TLS in any working form so it doesn't. Rather, since it knows what it's downloading, it downloads it to a .part file, checks the SHA-256 hash against the known value in the installer, and only then renames it to an .exe file and runs it.

You will not encounter this user agent unless you're implementing a transparent proxy. The point here is cases do come up where http makes more sense than https.

A similar use case for HTTP-only is Linux software packages.  They're usually cryptographically signed, and can be uniquely identified just by the filesize, so HTTPS provides neither security nor privacy, while preventing caching.

@Mark There are definitely use cases for HTTP - and I did not disclaim this- in fact I specifically stated that.   What I am saying is that HTTP CLIENTS really need to support the HTTPS protocol - and indeed the Linux package managers I am aware of do.    Also "can be uniquely identified just by the filesize" is a dubious claim at best.  (The cryptographically signed and caching comments are, of-course, valid for the big package managers)

@davidgo, I've got a cache of every Gentoo package I've installed in the past 20 years, and for any size larger than a few kilobytes, the filesize uniquely identifies the package.  For example, if you see a download of 81,759,883 bytes, you know I've just installed NSS version 3.55.

Most browsers remember when they are able to connect to a domain securely and will upgrade requests to those domains in the future. You can take advantage of this by adding an invisible iframe to every insecure page load (or just to every page load). The iframe should use point to your website and use https. The content doesn't matter, it can be a blank page if you want.
If the iframe fails to load, nothing will happen. If it succeeds, the browser will remember your domain as a secure domain and in the future it will automatically upgrade all requests to https.
This has the obvious downside that the initial connection can be tampered with, removing the iframe and preventing upgrades in the future. It also will not upgrade the initial request automatically

Novel idea, but I question the execution - why use an iframe when a 1x1 image or piece of javacscript or css is much less of a security risk.   Its also worth noticing that this relies on the client and server both supporting HSTS (which is the technology you are referring to) - so this is a header that may need to be added to the output of the called site - and the initial connection to the site is still insecure.

The https version would need to set a Strict-Transport-Security. Otherwise, I don't think the browser could assume that, since the https version might be a completely different content than the http one.

If the user is running a text-only browser, iframes won't automatically load regardless of SSL support.
